# Add comment with type of XML element above element

Tags: xml, xsd

I want to know if I can add a comment similar to `<!--Optional:-->` with the type of element.

This is my actual XSD structure:

```
<xsd:complexType name="DATOS_REGISTRAPAGO_Type">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="numServicio"     nillable="false" type="tns:NumServicio_Type" />
        <xsd:element name="tipNegocio"      nillable="false" type="tns:TipNegocio_Type"/>
        <xsd:element name="mtoDeudor"       nillable="false" type="tns:MtoDeudorString_Type"/>
        <xsd:element name="fecEmision"      nillable="false" type="tns:FecEmision_Type"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:simpleType name="TipNegocio_Type">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>Tipo Negocio</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:maxLength value="2"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

This is my actual output:

```
<MENSAJEREQ>
        <INTEGREQ>
           <DETALLE>
              <DATOS>
                 <!--Optional:-->
                 <numServicio>?</numServicio>
                 <tipNegocio>?</tipNegocio>
                 <mtoDeudor>?</mtoDeudor>
              </DATOS>
           </DETALLE>
        </INTEGREQ>
     </MENSAJEREQ>
```

What I want:

```
<MENSAJEREQ>
        <INTEGREQ>
           <DETALLE>
              <DATOS>
                 <!--Optional:-->
                 <!--xs:string-->
                 <numServicio>?</numServicio>
                 <!--xs:string-->
                 <tipNegocio>?</tipNegocio>
                 <!--xs:int-->
                 <mtoDeudor>?</mtoDeudor>
              </DATOS>
           </DETALLE>
        </INTEGREQ>
     </MENSAJEREQ>
```

Comment: So, you would like to process an XML document along with its XSD and produce a copy of the XML document with comments added above each element that state the type of the element?    Yes, that sounds possible, but you have to let us know what language you'd like to use (XSLT would be ideal).   Also, protocol here is to show what you've done and ask for specific help (not just ask for code).

Comment: I'm working with OSB and I do a transformation of data, XSD structure of provider service to our internal XSD structure, what I need is to add this comment, I have seen that before but I don't know exactly where it should be, I'm not using XSTL or any specific language to do it, I supposed I had to modify something in my XSD file, for that reason I wrote that. We're using HTTP protocol.

Comment: If by "OSB" you mean Oracle Service Bus,  add such a tag to your question.   Realize that XSD only specifies validation criteria; it cannot add comments or manipulate XML in any way.  You'll have to "use XSLT or a specific language to do."   If you "do a transformation of the data" without using XSLT (or XQuery), then how are you doing the transformation?